# Using macports python 2.7 with macports qgis

Tags: qgis, installation, osx, python-2.7

I installed QGIS through macports on my mac running OSX 10.8.2 but when I run the application (QGIS 1.8) it says that I don't have python-gdal installed.

I searched Google and it appears that it is because QGIS is using the pre-installed version of Python that comes with OSX. I have my own version of Python 2.7 built through macports, and would like to use it with QGIS if possible.

Does anybody knows how to tell QGIS to use that version instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a bug, see http://trac.macports.org/ticket/36906.

You could use the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) version instead.